# Encrypt data using CryptoJS and decrypt using AESCipherService

Tags: javascript, encryption

I am trying to have an encryption/decryption setup. The encryption mode is ECB using the AES algorithm. For encryption, I am using CryptoJS as part of my application. The following code is used to encrypt:

```
        var keyHex = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key);
        alert(keyHex + ":" + keyHex.toString().length);


        var cipherText = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(inputString, keyHex, {mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB, padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding}).ciphertext);
        console.log("Encrypted: " + cipherText);
```

For decryption, I am using the AESCipherService of Shiro to decrypt. I have the following code:

```
public static String decryptUsingShiro(String base64EncodedData, String key) {
        byte[] base64decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(base64EncodedData.getBytes());
        AesCipherService decryptService = new AesCipherService();
        decryptService.setMode(OperationMode.ECB);
        decryptService.setPaddingScheme(PaddingScheme.PKCS5);
        ByteSource decrypt = decryptService.decrypt(base64decoded, key.getBytes());
        return new String(decrypt.getBytes());
    }
```

I get the following exception:

> Caused by: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must
>   be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher

Anything wrong I am doing on the encryption side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the padding mode "NoPadding", so the input must reach a complete block boundary (*n* * 16 bytes) in order to encrypt successfully. You should use [`PKCS7Padding`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7) instead. (*note: PKCS #7 is [referred to (incorrectly) as PKCS #5 in Java](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/9044/12569) -- they are essentially equivalent and for these purposes, `PaddingScheme.PKCS5` is correct.*)

In addition, [you should **not** use ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation). ECB is trivially broken and is not safe at all. Use an authenticated encryption mode (GCM/EAX/CCM) if possible, or CBC/CTR + HMAC if not.

Comment: thanks. that worked like a charm. I will be changing my code to use the CBC mode instead of ECB.